# Separated exception handling of a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I realize that I'd like the consumers of our API to not have to handle an exception. Or perhaps more clearly I'd like to ensure that the exception is always logged, but only the consumer will know how to handle success. I want the client to be able to handle the exception as well if they want, There is no valid `File` that I could return to them.

Note: `FileDownload` is a `Supplier<File>`

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<File> processDownload( final FileDownload fileDownload ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( fileDownload );
    fileDownload.setDirectory( getTmpDirectoryPath() );
    CompletableFuture<File> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( fileDownload, executorService );
    future... throwable -> {
        if ( throwable != null ) {
            logError( throwable );
        }
        ...
        return null; // client won't receive file.
    } );
    return future;

}
```

I don't really understand the `CompletionStage` stuff. Do I use `exception` or `handle`? do I return the original future or the future they return?

Comment: What do you want the result of your future to be if an exception is thrown? Should the consumer still receive the exception, or do you want them to be ignorant of what happened?

Comment: @Jeffrey I would expect them to receive the exception, handle it themselves as well if they want. I don't expect them to receive a File

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that you do not want to affect the result of your `CompletableFuture`, you'll want to use [`CompletableFuture::whenComplete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
future = future.whenComplete((t, ex) -> {
  if (ex != null) {
    logException(ex);
  }
});
```

Now when the consumer of your API tries to call `future.get()`, they will get an exception, but they don't necessarily need to do anything with it.

---

However, if you want to keep your consumer ignorant of the exception (return `null` when the `fileDownload` fails), you can use either [`CompletableFuture::handle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) or [`CompletableFuture::exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-):

```
future = future.handle((t, ex) -> {
  if (ex != null) {
    logException(ex);
    return null;
  } else {
    return t;
  }
});
```

or

```
future = future.exceptionally(ex -> {
  logException(ex);
  return null;
});
```

Comment: It’s much easier. A consumer being ignorant against exceptions can be simply chained using `future.thenAccept`. The key point here is that the consumer is never called in the exceptional case, so it doesn’t have to handle neither, an exception nor a `null` value. The bottom line is, don’t use `get()`…